# Bind: Invalid command `rl_complete'. for Swift in mac OS X

Tags: macos, swift

I was trying to launch swift REPL, when i type the command swift i get the below error.
I get the same error when i launch lldb compiler.

bind: Invalid command `rl_complete'.

Is this a problem. How should we rectify it?

Mac OsX 10.10.1
Macbook pro 2014

Comment: Which XCode version do you have installed?

Answer (score 3):

Check your `~/.editrc` file, which is the config for libedit (BSD replacement for readline). It may include config that conflicts with some programs - in my case, `lldb` and `swift`.